# Computational-science-careers tag - make synonym of career-development tag or remove?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should the computational-science-careers tag be made a synonym of the career-development tag?

At the time of writing, the former tag appears to have been newly created for [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40233/what-can-a-computational-scientist-do-in-the-fourth-industrial-revolution). An alternative would be to remove the computational-science-careers tag from that question.

I am assuming that since this is Computational Science Stack Exchange, careers questions will tend to be in the field of computational science by default.

Comment: I second leaving "career-development"